# how to convert number to numeric without loss of information R

Tags: r

In my data I have a column that contain a long value like the following number: `1469533935218` 
When I convert it to numeric it loss it's information and became like the following number:`1.469534e+12`

Comment: try  `options(scipen = 999)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not lose information when you convert it to numeric. See `options("digits")`. It is just a printing issue. Try setting `options(digits = 20)` then type `1469533935218` in your console.

When you type `1469533935218L` in the console (the suffix `L` tells R you want an `integer` rather than `double`) you get:

```
[1] 1.469534e+12
Warning message:
non-integer value 1469533935218L qualified with L; using numeric value
```

Because such integer is not representable in 32-bit mode. The "Details" section of `?integer` gives:

```
 Integer vectors exist so that data can be passed to C or Fortran
 code which expects them, and so that (small) integer data can be
 represented exactly and compactly.

 Note that current implementations of R use 32-bit integers for
 integer vectors, so the range of representable integers is
 restricted to about +/-2*10^9: ‘double’s can hold much larger
 integers exactly.
```

The very last sentence also tells you that no accuracy is lost.

---

If you want to hold `1469533935218` as an integer, you need @akrun's suggestion using 64-bit representation, as long as you are on a 64-bit machine with a 64-bit R. But my feeling is that there is no need to do so.

You also need to bear in mind the storage costs. If you keep data as `double`, each number is still 32-bit; if you keep data as 64-bit integer, it doubles the memory usage. In fact, if you later perform floating point computations with those numbers, you need them in `double` mode. So why not just use `double`?

Answer (score 0):

if we need to read a dataset with columns having big integers, load the `bit64` before using `fread`

```
library(bit64)
library(data.table)
dt1 <- fread("yourfile.csv")
```

Or using a reproducible example

```
dt2 <- fread("
      1469533935218,1469533935219
      14695339352223,1469533935323
   ")
dt2
#              V1            V2
#1:  1469533935218 1469533935219
#2: 14695339352223 1469533935323
```

Comment: You don't need to call `library(bit64)` for `fread` to read it correctly (it does by default) but it may be better for printing

Comment: It does. From the docs: `"integer64" (default) reads columns detected as containing integers larger than 2^31 as type bit64::integer64.`

Comment: @docendodiscimus I had a large transaction dataset which I read with `fread` sometime back where the ids are very long integers.  I thought it will pick up correctly, but when I checked for dupes, there was some problems.  So, I read it again with `bit64` and it got resolved.